# Is it necessary to taper two ends before fft a time series?

Tags: fft, filters, signal-analysis, lowpass-filter, speech-processing

I saw in some codes people always taper the ends of a signal using a cosine taper.

Is that necessary and why?

Comment: This is called windowing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tapering the two ends of a short audio signal allows it to be played at an arbitrary time after and before silence without a speaker "pop" or loud click.

Using a raised cosine taper reduces potential high frequency spectral content inherent in any sudden sharp startup transient, which might not be present in the rest of the data due to prior low pass filtering.

Comment: so, if there is an impulse at the start, the lowpass filtering cannot remove it?

Comment: A sufficiently low low-pass filter might have a similar effect on the ends, but at a higher computational cost.